# VUEX: Unexpected token, expected "," (axios)

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

I'm calling an weather API to display the weather data of user's current location using axios. But it's seems like there has a syntax error, but I coudn't find out where I coded wrong. Please help me.

```
actions:{
         currentCity({commit}) {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
                axios
                .get(`${this.url_base}weather?&lat=${position.coords.latitude}&lon=${position.coords.longitude}&units=metric&APPID=${this.api_key}`)
                .then(res=>res.data)
                .then(weather=>{
                    commit('currentCity',weather)
                })            
    }}}
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use your IDE. You clearly don't open and close your braces and parentheses in the right order. If you click over a closing brace/parentheses in most editors (including even google chrome JS console which is what i used to find this) it will highlight the opening one making it very quick and easy to find your syntax errors...

```
actions: {
    currentCity({commit})
    {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
                axios
                    .get(`${this.url_base}weather?&lat=${position.coords.latitude}&lon=${position.coords.longitude}&units=metric&APPID=${this.api_key}`)
                    .then(res => res.data)
                    .then(weather => {
                        commit('currentCity', weather)
                    })
            })
        }
    }
}
```